# How to manipulate one string to upper case and lower case

Tags: java

This is a homework assignment where we need to get input from the user to enter their first and last name with a space inbetween. Upon entering this data, the user presses enter and will be asked to enter their alias name. once thats entered the program outputs the user inputted first and last name and adds "aka" and the user inputted alias name and also display the initials of the first and last name in lower case letters, upper case letters, and the persons first and last name in all lower case letters. I have successfully got the program to display the first and last name and aka alias name as well as initials. But I cannot figure out how I can get the initial to be to instances "AB" and "ab" and also how to get the user input and make it all lower case letters.

```
    /*
    * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
     * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
    */

 package aliassearch;
 import java.awt.*;
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.util.Scanner; 
  /**
  *
  * @author students
  */
 public class Aliassearch {
  public static int user_input;
  /**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    Scanner user_input = new Scanner (System.in);

    String first_name;

    System.out.print("Please put in your first name followed by a space and a last name: ");
    first_name = user_input.nextLine();



    String s = new String(first_name); 
    int slength = s.length();      
   //System.out.println(slength); //


    int sindex = s.indexOf(" ");
   // System.out.println(sindex);


    //alias parts
    String alias_name;
    System.out.print("Enter your alias: ");
    alias_name = user_input.next();

    // combines user input first name and alias name
    String full_name;
    full_name = first_name + " " + alias_name;

    System.out.println(first_name + " aka " + alias_name  );

     //converts to initials
    for (int i = 1; i < first_name.length(); i++) {
    char c1 = first_name.charAt(i);

    if (c1 == ' ') {
    System.out.print(first_name.charAt(i - 7));
    System.out.print(first_name.charAt(i + 1));
    System.out.print(".");

    String result;
    result = s.toLowerCase();


 }


 }

 }}
```

Comment: Well did you research at all? :) there are so many answers on google within a second. For one solution, look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase(). I will let you think about how to solve your other problem. Hint, the solution is probably within the `String` class again.

Answer (score 0):

As his is your homework, all i can do is refer you to the official [String class documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). You'll find your answer sooner rather than later :)

Answer (score 0):

use toUpperCase method from String class.
something like

> String aliasUpper = alias_name.toUpperCase();